# Normalize redux-form field value onBlur

Tags: redux-form

How can I normalize the value of the **redux-form** field when **onBlur** is triggered. I tried the following, but it didn't seem to work:

```
const normalizeAmount = (node) => {
  const newValue = node.target.value;

  return `--${newValue}--`;
};

render() {
    const { handleSubmit, pristine, invalid, submitting, error, blur } = this.props;

return (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(submit)}>
        <div name="form-container">
          <Field
            name="foo"
            component={CustomInput}
            onBlur={blurValue => blur(normalizeValue(blurValue))}
          /> 
          ...
);
```

Answer (score 10):

Solved this by moving onBlur to **CustomInput** component, where I add

```
return (
   <div>
    <input
      ...
      onBlur={value => props.input.onBlur(normalizeValue(value))}
    />
   </div>
);
```

And in the form component the field will just have:

```
<Field
   name="foo"
   component={CustomInput}
/>
```

Comment: the onBlur={value => props.input.onBlur(normalizeValue(value))} part is a little missleading....  onBlur={event => props.input.onBlur(normalizeValue(event))} looks better

Comment: how can i use the event to se the field value?

Answer (score 0):

actually `normalize` is used before any changing in field so it's used before `onBlur` event, but you are trying to use it in wrong way.

You can use something like this and to allow user to enter only numbers:

```
<Field component={TextInputField}                                     
   onBlur={value => this.doWhatEverYouNeed(value)}
   normalize={value => value.replace(/[^\d]/g, '')}
/>
```

More details about normalize you can find on https://redux-form.com/8.2.2/examples/normalizing/